# Invalid argument in foreach - FB graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, foreach, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invalid argument in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475891/invalid-argument-in-foreach)

I'm simply trying to parse FB graphi API results.

When I try the foearch loop I get Invalid Argument error

Here's the code

```
$url = urlencode("http://***.com/pages/view?id=2153&item=Mens-Collection-Shoes");

$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=".$url;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
$fb_response = json_decode($requests, true);

foreach($fb_response->data as $item){
echo $item->message . '<br />';
echo $item->from->id . '<br />';
echo $item->from->name . '<br />';
echo $item->message . '<br />';
echo $item->created_time . '<br /><br />';
}
```

When i dump `$requests` I get (formatted by me):

```
{"http:\/\/***.com\/pages\/view?id=2153&item=Mens-Collection-Shoes":
{"comments":
{"data":[
{"id":"***_78606","from":
{
"name":"Laura","id":"***"},
"message":"I love these.",
"can_remove":
false,
"created_time":"2012-11-20T10:20:16+0000",
"like_count":0,
"user_likes":false
}],
"paging":{
"next":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/***\/comments?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=***_78606"
}}}}
```

Any ideas? probably something simple I can't see

Have tried with and without `urlencode` but no difference

Comment: try var_dump($fp_response) or print_r($fp_response); dumping the response itself is not the same as dumping what php has turned it into with json_decode

Comment: The dump shown is $requests, which is before the json_decode

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

`json_decode($blah, TRUE)`

returns an array... not an object, try removing the true from

`$fb_response = json_decode($requests, true);`