# Invalid argument in foreach

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, foreach, json

I am using the following to retrieve comments from FB:

```
$url = urlencode("http://*****.com/pages/view?id=2153&item=Mens-Collection-Shoes");
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=" . $url;
$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);
```

when I `print_r($requests);` I get the following but cannot work out how to format it with a foreach loop:

```
{
    "http:\/\/*****.com\/pages\/view?id=2153&item=Mens-Collection-Shoes": {
        "comments": {
            "data": [{
                "id": "123456",
                    "from": {
                    "name": "Laurelle",
                        "id": "123456"
                },
                    "message": "I love these",
                    "can_remove": false,
                    "created_time": "2012-11-20T10:20:16+0000",
                    "like_count": 0,
                    "user_likes": false
            } {
                "id": "123456",
                    "from": {
                    "name": "Dan",
                        "id": "123456"
                },
                    "message": "I know, just stunning!",
                    "can_remove": false,
                    "created_time": "2012-11-20T14:24:15+0000",
                    "like_count": 0,
                    "user_likes": false
            }],
                "paging": {
                "next": "https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/*****\/comments?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=*****"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get:

```
data->from->id
data->from->name
data->message
data->created_time
```

I've tried:

```
$fb_response = json_decode($requests);

foreach($fb_response->data as $item){
echo $item->from->id . '<br />';
echo $item->from->name . '<br />';
echo $item->message . '<br />';
echo $item->created_time . '<br /><br />';
}
```

But no luck

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$fb_response` after the `json_decode()` statement?

Comment: I'll wager he hasn't because he asked the exact same question earlier and I said the exact same thing

Comment: @Dale I did try what you said in last post, but closed it as it was written in a confusing way, my fault - as you can see from the answer below, your answer didn't solve the issue I had, but, I appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
$originalUrl = "http://*****.com/pages/view?id=2153&item=Mens-Collection-Shoes";
$url = urlencode($originalUrl);
...
foreach($fb_response->$originalUrl->comments->data as $item) {
```

`data` isn't the name of a property directly inside the JSON document; it's under `http://*****.com/pages/view?id=2153&item=Mens-Collection-Shoes` and `comments`.

Comment: Damn! Of course.. can't see the wood for the trees sometimes! Many thanks, it's appreciated.